# Enqueued stylesheet appends query string, causing "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: errors, wp-enqueue-style

```
function renderProductPageUi() {
  wp_enqueue_style('stylesheetHandle', plugins_url('pluginName/semantic/dist/semantic.css'));

  require_once ('templates/offerBox.php');
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'renderProductPageUi');
```

In Chrome browser I see this red console error:

```
http://localhost/wptest2/wp-content/plugins/pluginName/semantic/dist/semantic.css?ver=5.1.1
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Notice the `?ver=5.1.1` at the end. I vaguely recall this being a wordpress behavior. Is that what is causing the console error? If so how should it be corrected?

Comment: Is that your actual code? The error message suggests you’ve tried to enqueue a CSS file as JavaScript.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, I had a duplicate line, except `wp_enqueue_script()` for the semantic.js file but forgot to change the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` is not an error that you will ever see related to CSS. This is a *JavaScript* error that occurs when there's a syntax error in some JavaScript. If you see this error and it's occurring in a CSS file, then it means that you have improperly loaded a CSS file in `<script>` tag, which means the browser will try to parse the CSS as JavaScript, which will inevitably produce a syntax error, because CSS is not valid JavaScript.

This will happen in WordPress if you try to use `wp_enqueue_script()` on a CSS file. Make sure you only use `wp_enqueue_script()` for JavaScript files, and `wp_enqueue_style()` for CSS files.